# png watermark images not apply on psd file using imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, watermark, composite, psd

/usr/local/bin/composite -gravity center "/tmp/watermark_12809_1657557870.png" "/tmp/1657557870-sample1.psd" "Rams_1657557871.psd"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, the first layer of the PSD file is usually the flattened image. So try

```
/usr/local/bin/composite -gravity center "/tmp/watermark_12809_1657557870.png" "/tmp/1657557870-sample1.psd[0]" "Rams_1657557871.psd"
```